# What is $TxfLog?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I was using recovery software on my drive and I found this "$TxfLog" in the $Extend metadata file on my NTFS.  What is it?  It's currently holding some files with several megabytes.

Comment: Don't know what it is or why it's there.

Comment: is your question answered?

Answer (score 4):

Since [Windows Vista, NTFS supports Transactions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) This is the log file for the transactions system.

So this is a normal file that you see.

Comment: Do you know if it is needed?

Comment: yes, the log file is needed, because Txf is used by several Windows components.